# How to convert igraph network plot to ggnet2 in R?

Tags: r, igraph, ggnetwork

I have created a network plot using `igraph` In `R`. However, I feel it might be easier to manipulate legends etc using `ggnet2`. So, I am trying to convert or achieve a similar plot using `igraph`... but using `ggnet2`. But I am unfamiliar with `ggnet2` and I'm working my way through the manual but I can't get it to work for my basic example.

Below is a basic example of how I'm creating the network plot using igraph:

```
library(igraph)
edgeWe <- c(1,2,10,3,4,2,3,4,4,20)
edgeDir <- c(1,2, 1,3, 1,4, 1,5, 2,3, 2,4, 2,5, 3,4, 3,5, 4,5 )
nodeSize <- c(9, 19, 29, 39, 49)

net.xy <- make_graph(edgeDir, 5, directed = F)
V(net.xy)$size <- nodeSize
E(net.xy)$width <- edgeWe

lo <- layout_in_circle(net.xy)
plot(net.xy, lo)
```

This produces a plot similar to this:

[image: igraph network plot]

I know there are parameters like `node.size` in `ggnet2`... but my main difficulty
is even producing a graph similar to this.

Any suggestions as to how I would achieve this?